# Is there something faster than AsymptoticDSolveValue for getting the terms in a power series solution?

Tags: series-expansion, asymptotics

Here's an example of a differential equation which Mathematica 13.1 just returns without solving

```
DSolve[{y''[x] + (5 x^3 + 3 x^2 + 5 x + 1) y'[x] + x y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 2}, y[x], x]
```

This specific differential equation isn't so important, it's just an example. If you want a power series solution around $x = 0$ you can do something like

```
AsymptoticDSolveValue[{y''[x] + (5 x^3 + 3 x^2 + 5 x + 1) y'[x] + x y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 2}, y[x], {x, 0, 1000}];
```

The problem is that I don't need 1,000 terms, I need more like 1,000,000 and that's going to take ages. I assume - perhaps wrongly - that if you painstakingly derived the recurrence relation for the coefficients in the power series solution, a command like `RecurrenceTable[]` would get the terms much faster, especially if we only need floats and not the exact values. But is there an automatic way to do this?

Comment: I would go with finding the recurrence first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't obtain the recurrence formula with V 13.1

Looking at "Q&A with Calculus Developers: Live with the R&D team" Nov 30, 2022 at
https://www.twitch.tv/videos/1666674721 for V 13.2,  I did not see this feature being there (see around 7 minutes frame).  Not even Maple can do this for series solutions. i.e. give explicit recurrence formula used for series solution.

I have a function myself that does this (but still in development) and it only handle linear 1st and second order odes'. For your ode, this is the recurrence formula it found

$n=0$ gives
$$
a_{2} = -\frac{a_{1}}{2}
$$
$n=1$ gives
$$
a_{3} = -\frac{a_{0}}{6}-\frac{2 a_{1}}{3}
$$
$n=2$ gives
$$
a_{4} = \frac{a_{0}}{24}+\frac{a_{1}}{4}
$$
For $3\le n$, the recurrence equation is
$$
a_{n +2}= -\frac{5 n a_{n}}{\left(n +2\right) \left(n +1\right)}-\frac{\left(5 n -10\right) a_{n -2}}{\left(n +2\right) \left(n +1\right)}-\frac{\left(3 n -2\right) a_{n -1}}{\left(n +2\right) \left(n +1\right)}-\frac{a_{n +1}}{n +2}
$$

Now you are able to generate very fast all terms you want. Here is the Mathematica code

```
a[2] = -a[1]/2
a[3] = -a[0]/6 - 2 a[1]/3
a[4] = a[0]/24 + a[1]/4
Table[a[n + 2] = -5*n*a[n]/((n + 2)*(n + 1)) - (5*n - 10)*
     a[n - 2]/((n + 2)*(n + 1)) - (3*n - 2)*
     a[n - 1]/((n + 2)*(n + 1)) - a[n + 1]/(n + 2), {n, 3, 10}];
sol = Sum[a[n]*x^n, {n, 0, 10}];
Collect[sol, {a[0], a[1]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to

```
AsymptoticDSolveValue[{y''[x] + (5 x^3 + 3 x^2 + 5 x + 1) y'[x] + 
    x y[x] == 0}, y[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that I generates all the $a_n$ using normal `Table` command. You could try to use `RecurrenceTable` instead to see if performance is better.

You can now solve for $a_0,a_1$ easily given the initial conditions.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that but it is what it is. It's not TOO bad to substitute `a[n] z^n` into the differential equation and re-index appropriately, wish it was built-in though.

Comment: @Mr.G that will work for only ordinary points. For regular singular point you need to use Frobenius series, Now you can't just do what you said like this, as first you need to find the indicial equation. It gets complicated quickly. For irregular singular point, you have to use asymptotic methods. standard series methods no longer works. btw, the **and re-index appropriately** is not that easy. There are many edge cases to take care of and so on. Try to code it and you will see it is not trivial but still much easier for ordinary point that regular singular points. Your ode is ordinary point.

Comment: Oh sure, I completely believe the general case is a nightmare but luckily I don't have to deal with that.

Comment: The bottom of this section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_integration#Recent_advances seems to say that there is a Maple package algolib that can compute the recurrence formulas. That said it's just my vague understanding of the text and I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the coefficients using [`SeriesCoefficient`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesCoefficient.html) on the [`DifferentialRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferentialRoot.html) of the differential equation

```
f = DifferentialRoot[
  Function[{y, 
    x}, {y''[x] + (5 x^3 + 3 x^2 + 5 x + 1) y'[x] + x y[x] == 0, 
    y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 2}]]

rec = SeriesCoefficient[f[x], {x, 0, n}][[1, 1, 1, 0, 1]][y, n]
```

`(* {5 n y[n] + (4 + 3 n) y[1 + n] + (10 + 5 n) y[2 + n] + (3 + n) y[ 3 + n] + (3 + n) (4 + n) y[4 + n] == 0, y[0] == 1, y[1] == 2,  y[2] == -1, y[3] == -(3/2)} *)`

In LaTeX :

$$ \left\{5 n y(n)+(3 n+4) y(n+1)+(5 n+10) y(n+2)+(n+3) y(n+3)+(n+3) (n+4) y(n+4)=0,y(0)=1,y(1)=2,y(2)=-1,y(3)=-\frac{3}{2}\right\} $$

To compare with @Nasser 's recurrence we can use:

```
Solve[rec[[1]] /. n -> n - 2, y[2 + n]][[1, 1]] // Simplify
```

`(* y[2 + n] -> -( 1/((1 + n) (2 + n)))(5 (-2 + n) y[-2 + n] + (-2 + 3 n) y[-1 + n] +  5 n y[n] + y[1 + n] + n y[1 + n]) *)`

In LaTeX

$$ y(n+2)\to -\frac{5 (n-2) y(n-2)+(3 n-2) y(n-1)+5 n y(n)+n y(n+1)+y(n+1)}{(n+1) (n+2)} $$